# Creating a link from dynamically generated data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im using jQuery mobile and I have a list of items generated from javascript which calls a server-side php script connecting to a mysql database and outputting it to a JSON array. It works perfectly the example is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url="http://www.mysite.com/json.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
var output='<ul data-role="listview">';
$.each(json.menu,function(key,val) {
    output+='<li>';
    output+= '<a href="#menuitem" onclick="showItem(' + val.menu_title + ')">';
    output+='<h3>' + val.menu_title + '</h3>';
    output+='<img src="' +val.menu_img +'" />';
    output+='<p>' +val.menu_desc + '</p>';
    output+= '</a>';
    output+='</li>';
});
output+='</ul>';
$('#menulist').html(output);
});
})
```

What I need is a showItem function so when I click on a single item in the list view it will pass that information to a dynamically created page detailing that single item. Hopefully there is an easy answer, I've tried a few different things and none of them work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the dynamically added elements click functions aren't firing?

Comment: I can click on the item and it will take me to the #menuitem page but it is blank. I created a function for the onclick="showItem(' + val.menu_title + ')">'; but it doesnt work. I am a noob to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to retrieve some more information from your server. If you want to view a dynamically created page, detailing a single item, you are going to need some type of `ID`.

1. I would suggesting adding the `ID` to line 7 of your code *(where
   you created the opening part of the a tag)* and add the id there,
   say to the `href` and strip off the `onclick`
2. Then I would add a class to the `a tag` say `details`
3. Your end result should look a little like this:

`output+= '<a class="details" href="#itemid-' + val.itemid + '">';`

Lastly, add the following jQuery

```
$( '#menulist' ).on( 'click', '.details', function () {
    // Whatever your navigation is, it should go here
    // Eg: window.location = this.href;
});`
```

Comment: This works...sort of. Now when I hover over the item I see it appends the menu_id to the url like so: http://www.mysite.com/#menuitem1 but when I click on it nothing happens.